# C#, Using Task.Run to run method, but the code is not executing

Tags: c#, wpf, task, task-parallel-library

Hi i am trying to use separate tasks to run methods in the back ground of a WPF application, i have 2 Tasks using Task.Run to fire off other methods in other classes. The first one works absolutly fine. I am using c#

called after a button click:

```
try
          {
            Task loading = Task.Run(() => cleaner.startCleanProcess());
            txt_Progress.Text += "The data clean is in progress \r";
            timer = new DispatcherTimer
            {
                Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)
            };
            timer.Tick += Timer_CleanProgress;

            timer.IsEnabled = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            do exception stuff
        }
```

the method is inside the cleaner class and looks like:

```
     public void startCleanProcess()
     {
          try
          {  
              do stuff
          }
     }
```

the second one is the same set up, but the code inside the method never executes

is called on a button click:

```
try
            {
                Task updating = Task.Run(() => newUpdateManager.RunUpdate(txt_BatchFilePath.Text));
                //newUpdateManager.RunUpdate(txt_BatchFilePath.Text);
                txt_Progress.Text += "\rRunning the update through Middleware";
                timer = new DispatcherTimer
                {
                    Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)
                };
                timer.Tick += Timer_UpdateProgress;
                timer.IsEnabled = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                do exception stuff
            }
```

the RunUpdate method is set up like:

```
    public void RunUpdate(string filepath) {
                try
                {
                    string[] arraystring = { "hello", "world" };
                    File.WriteAllLines(filepath, arraystring);

                }
     }
```

does anyone happen to see anything immediatly wrong with this set up? when i step through, the task says its running, but nothing happens (these methods are simplified for obvious reasons) but as far as i can tell the second method is never actually started. break points dont get hit, the file never gets written. if i start the method off directly instead of using Task it runs fine and dandy. 
im only asking if anyone can see if i have set this up wrong as i have been stuck on it all day and fear that my brain may have stopped.

thanks for your time

Comment: `Task updating = Task.Run(() => newUpdateManager.RunUpdate(txt_BatchFilePath.Text));` -> `string batchFilePath = txt_BatchFilePath.Text; Task updating = Task.Run(() => newUpdateManager.RunUpdate(batchFilePath));`?

Comment: First off your accessing a ui element, `...Text`, from a default context. Have you tried to debug this?

Comment: You have a cross threading issue.

Comment: You are not catching exceptions good enough. You have `try-catch` inside RunUpdate, but exception is thrown before that, when accessing `txt_batchFilePath.Text` from non-UI thread. This exception goes unnoticed, and because of it - RunUpdate never actually runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @JSteward and @Ron Beyer said, you have a cross threading issue. You should run the code in debug and see the cross thread error.

To avoid that, one thing you can do is to get the text in a variable and pass that variable in the `Task.Run()` method.

```
var batchFilePath = txt_BatchFilePath.Text;
Task updating = Task.Run(() => newUpdateManager.RunUpdate(batchFilePath));
```